# Split String by Character NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string

I have a song, as such:

```
[Intro]

[Verse 1]
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy

[Pre-Chorus 1]
I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling
Gotta make you understand
```

I want to split it by the `[` character so then I now have three strings as such:

```
[Intro]
```

```
[Verse 1]
We're no strangers to love
You know the rules and so do I
A full commitment's what I'm thinking of
You wouldn't get this from any other guy
```

```
[Pre-Chorus 1]
I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling
Gotta make you understand
```

And save each of these as a separate string.

How can this be done? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `var parts = song.split("[")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a regex match on the entire header bracket, start with the open square bracket, and match any character other than the closing bracket. Then match for anything after the closing bracket that isn't an opening bracket to get all the text after the header.

```
let test = "[intro]text[verse 1]to split[verse 2]on";
let matches = test.match(/(\[[^\]]+\][^\[]+)/g);
```

This will return a result of:

```
(3) ["[intro]↵text", "[verse 1]to split", "[verse 2]on"]
0: "[intro]↵text"
1: "[verse 1]to split"
2: "[verse 2]on"
```

This all assumes you won't have any random square brackets in the header labels that aren't part of a header, but I believe it should get you your desired result.